# If selector hidden, perform function on another selector

Tags: jquery, css, toggle, hidden

I'm a bit of a noob and can't figure out how to make my if statement work.

All I want to do is position `box2` 210px to the left if class `box1` is hidden.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("span:eq(0)").click(function(){
        $(".box1").toggle("slow");
    });

    $("span:eq(1)").click(function(){
        $(".box2").toggle("slow");
    });

    $("span:eq(2)").click(function(){
        $(".box3").toggle("slow");
    });

    $("span:eq(3)").click(function(){
        $(".box4").toggle("slow");
    });

    if($(".box1").is(":hidden")){
       $(".box2").css("left","210px");
    } else {
        return;
    }
});
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Here's a [jFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YpqCg/9/)

Comment: I can't tell what is not working as desired in your fiddle

Comment: What's the point of `else{ return; }`

Comment: @Blazemonger what should I set to zero?

Comment: @j08691 I was just fiddling with different options and thought you had to have a else statement with an if statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:**

Try this new [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alessandroaje/YpqCg/17/)

I call the function after toggle was finished:

```
$("span:eq(0)").click(function(){
      $(".box1").toggle("slow", function(){
          changeProperty();   
      });          
});
```

I think that when you verify if is hidden or not, the element have ever the property display = block, but if you call after `toggle()` it return the real state of element.

```
function changeProperty(){

    if($(".box1").is(":hidden")){
         $(".box2").css({"left":"210px"});
     }
    else
     {
        $(".box2").css({"left":"0"});
     }
}
```

Comment: what if you want to do it when it's hidden?

Comment: you can use `$(selector).not(':visible')`

Comment: this has made box2 dissappear when I hide box1

Comment: because the property `$(".box2").css("left","210px");` put the box2 behind the box3, change the left to other value and see

Comment: it also put the 2nd box to the right when everything is visible

Comment: Can you check the new fiddle? @patwick600akabob

Comment: thanks for the answer, I've used absolute positioning and it worked

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you wanted?

```
     if($(".box1").is(":hidden")){
         $(".box2").css("left","210px");
     }else{
         $(".box2").css("left","0"); // default
     }
```

Comment: for some reason that doesn't work on the jfiddle, basically the top right blue box should stay where it is...

Comment: Perhaps you should change the `visibility` of the boxes instead of toggling them?

Answer (score 0):

Try to edit this: hope this would help you.

```
if($(".box1").is(":hidden")){
         $(".box2").css({"left":"210px"});
     }
else
     {
        $(".box2").css({"left":"0"});
     }
```